# PHP MySQL Admin Level

Tags: php, mysql

This is my user table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `level` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

So lets say I am on index.php

I want that if user level = 1, then he can see a link appear on the page. Other wise if level = 0, he will never see that link.

How can I do that?

Comment: and where is your php code?

Comment: which part do you require?

Comment: I just want to add like if (level =1){ <a href=...><a> }. isnt it something like that?

Comment: anything in your `index.php` did you try anything so far?

Comment: Yes my index file is got other stuff. its a forum script. categories, topics etc.
What I want to do is add a link that goes to users.php where you can see the list of users. users.php works fine.
I just want to hide that link from everyone, just the people who have level = 1 can see it, in other words only admins. But I dont have an admin system, I just made a level attribute

Comment: did you try assigning the `level` into `$_SESSION['level']`? and use conditional statement in view check if `$_SESSION['level']` is `1` or `0` ?

Comment: i dont know exactly how to write it. I did this if(isset($_SESSION['level = 1'])){
                echo "Link";
            }
But it doesnt work

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['level']) && (int) $_SESSION['level'] === 1){ echo "Link"; }` something like that see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Hmm, nothing is showing

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this.

in your login module do something like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['level'] = 1; // passed the level from you database.
```

and in your pages.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (int) $_SESSION['level'] === 1) {
    echo '<a>Link for admin</a>';
}
```

Comment: login module you mean in my login.php?

Comment: what value did you passed to `$_SESSION['level']`?

Comment: this is my index.php pastebin.com/bA1tTq5c, and this is my login.php pastebin.com/5k4xsAxs before adding the level stuff.
Parts of the code

Comment: one more thing!! I see you still using `mysql_query()` it's now deprecated and vulnerable to `sql injection` you should use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: how hard is it to change my whole script to mysqli? is there a converter tool?

Comment: not that hard. see this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp)

Comment: I decided to change level from integer 1 to string Administrator. 
How this will change? if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && (int) $_SESSION['level'] === 1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use session codes. Set a session code value to the value of `level`, and depending on that value display the link or not.

Comment: like this? if(isset($_SESSION['level = 1'])){
                echo "Link";
            }

Comment: @Mista Josh above illustrates the idea fairly well. You need to set level in your database first, and then set the session value based on the level database entry as he does.

Comment: @KyleBooth he mentioned he was unsure how to write the code, by just giving him the theory you are not really answering the question 100% hence my answer (not like it matters now anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SESSION. So for example when your user logs in, you can set the session variable for level such as:

When your user logs in:

```
session_start(); // You must use this at the beginning of every page you use $_SESSION on
// Query here to select your user
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
//$username is the username of the user who is logging in.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
    }
}
```

On your index.php page (or any other page you want to check the user level):

```
session_start(); // This is reqd once on any page you use $_SESSION
// Then on your page you can use 
if (!empty($_SESSION['level']) && $_SESSION['level'] == 1)
{
    echo '<a href="">Your Link</a>';
}
```

Comment: this is my index.php http://pastebin.com/bA1tTq5c, and this is my login.php http://pastebin.com/5k4xsAxs

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName", 'dbUser', 'dbPassword');

    //Check username and password
    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT level FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?");
    $sth->execute(array('user2@email.com', '2222')); // these values are passed via SESSION, POST, etc
                                                     //make sure to encrypt password
    $user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($user) && $user['level'] == 1) {
        echo "link";
    }  else {
        echo "no-link";
    }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```